# how to sort a list of string by every element's numeric value

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of string like this:

```
a = ["part 1", "part 3" , "part 10", "part 2"....]
```

If I sort them and print, `sorted[a]`the result is

```
["part 1", "part 10", "part 2", "part 3"]
```

But I want to sort them as:

```
["part 1", "part 2", "part 3", "part 10"]
```

by the numeric value in each string. How can I implement that? Thanks

Comment: Dup: [Does Python have a built in function for string **natural sort**?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = ["part 1", "part 3" , "part 10", "part 2"]
print sorted(a, key=lambda x:int(x.split()[1]))
```

**Output**

```
['part 1', 'part 2', 'part 3', 'part 10']
```

If you want to sort in-place,

```
a.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split()[1]))
print a
```